# Combinatorics: How many non-negative integer solutions are there to the following equation: x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 = 1000000

Tags: combinatorics

> Combinatorics: How many non-negative integer solutions are there to the following equation: x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 = 1000000

I thought to look at the equation as x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 = $2^6$ * $5^6$.

and then there are 4C2 * 4 * 4 solutions.

what do you think?

Comment: It’s considerably more than that. Try an easier problem first: how many non-negative integer solutions are there to $x_1x_2x_3x_4=64$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate this, but I tried to write the possibilities manually and I found 18 solutions.. is It correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You’re way short, I’m afraid. It looks to me like you’re missing a key idea, so I’ve written up an answer to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you think ${4\choose 2}\cdot 4\cdot 4$ is the answer.  What four things are you choosing two of?  And which two things have four options each? Is this a good mathematical model?

Comment: So $x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 2^65^6$. So each $x_i = 2^{a_i}5^{b_i}$ for some integers $a_i,b_i$.  What particular restrictions are there on $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$?  can you set up a model to answer how many sets of values $a_i, b_i$ can be?

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing quite a bit, I’m afraid. We can break it into two problems. If $x_1x_2x_3x_4=10^6$, then the numbers $x_k$ must be of the form $x_k=2^{a_k}5^{b_k}$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. Then we’ll have a solution in non-negative integers to the original equation if and only if

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=6\tag{1}$$

and

$$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=6\,,\tag{2}$$

where the $a_k$ and $b_k$ are non-negative integers. Counting the solution in non-negative integers to $(1)$ is a basic [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem; the linked article has a pretty good explanation of the reasoning involved. The same goes for $(2)$, of course; in fact, the number of solutions will obviously be the same.

Once you have that number, you’ve done the hardest part. Now, taking into account the fact that the powers of $2$ can be distributed amongst $x_1,x_2,x_3$, and $x_4$ completely independently of the powers of $5$, what do you do with the numbers of solutions to $(1)$ and $(2)$ to finish off the problem?